# Parameter stability in CAPM (with R)

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

Im trying to test for parameter stability using the CAPM. Basically, I have a stock and the market index, and I try to assess whether after a specific event, the beta of the regression changes significantly.

If you are not familiar with CAPM, basically is a simple regression that gives us the required return of a stock, based on the risk free rate and the market index.

It would look like this: *Rr = alpha + B(Rmkt-rf) + e*

I wanted to add a dummy and a dummy interaction variable to turn the model into this:

*Rr* = *Alpha + Alpha*(break) + B(Rmkt-rf)+ B(Rmkt-rf)*(break) + e*

So the break variable would be 0 for the period before the event, and 1 after the event. in this way I intend to capture both a switch in the intercept (with the alpha) and in the slope (with the beta) if those estimators are significant.

To tho that, I get the symbols with getSymbols:

```
ARG=ARGT$ARGT.Adjusted
WORLD=XWD.TO$XWD.TO.Adjusted
```

**Note that ARG is my stock, and WORLD is my market index**

I then only use the adjusted versions, as they are corrected for splits.

```
ARG=ARGT$ARGT.Adjusted
WORLD=XWD.TO$XWD.TO.Adjusted
```

I then proceed to obtain the weekly returns with the weeklyReturn function of quantmod:

```
WEKar=weeklyReturn(ARG, subset=NULL, type='arithmetic',leading=TRUE)

WEKwo=weeklyReturn(WORLD, subset=NULL, type='arithmetic',leading=TRUE)
```

After that, I need the excess returns, so I use a given risk free rate given: (Weekly) of rf=0.61/52 which I name rf

so

```
#WEEKLY EXCESS RETURNS
WexretAR=(WEKar-rf)
WexretWO=(WEKwo-rf)
```

(I am not sure if that is correct to do so as to analyse the excess return.)

Then I proceed to create my dummy variable, namely, a column of 0 and 1 before and after the alleged break.

```
 WexretWO$dummy <- rep(0,length(WexretWO[,1]))
 for(i in 254:length(WexretWO[,1])){
 WexretWO$dummy[i]<- 1
 }

interaction <- rep(0,length(WexretWO[,1]))
for(i in 1:length(WexretWO[,1])){
interaction[i] <- WexretWO$weekly.returns[i] * WexretWO$dummy[i]
}
```

I then proceed with my regression with the dummy interaction in this way:

```
betaregres2=lm(WexretAR ~ WexretWO$weekly.returns + WexretWO$dummy + 
interaction)
summary(betaregres2)
```

My question is if you guys think this is the correct approach for such a task? I would really be interested in knowing your opinion on dealing with such breaks and if this is the most efficient manner of evaluating them.

Thank you in advance and I am sorry for any mistakes or sloppiness. I am new to this.

Juan